# Querying records and making them groups from SQLite Table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, greendao, greendao-generator

I am not really understanding how can this be done in single query.

PROBLEM:

I have a table like this

```
id| phonenumber| message| group_name| datetime
```

Example data

```
1 | 987654321 | "hi"    | G1 | xxxxxxx
2 | 987654321 | "hi"    | G1 | xxxxxxx
1 | 987145678 | "hello" | G2 | xxxxxxx
```

What I want to do is query the above SqlLite table in such a way that I need to grab all the rows of particular phonenumber in Descending order of `datetime`. So that I can put them in my HashMap with key as `group_name` and value as ArrayList of `messages`.

```
 HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mapper = new HashMap<>();
```

I am using GreenDao Library to fetch data from SqlLite, I tried like below

```
    List<activity> activities = activityDao.queryBuilder().where(new WhereCondition.StringCondition(com.ficean.android.ficean.db.activityDao.Properties.Contact_number.eq(phonenumber) + "GROUP BY group_name")).orderDesc(com.ficean.android.ficean.db.activityDao.Properties.Date_time).build().list();
```

I managed to do above query using `GROUP BY` but it is not listing  all rows.Do I have to get All data of particular number and separate it looping through each row based on group_name ? or is there any better way to do?

Comment: And why do you need this HashMap ? Looks like you just want to store all your database in memory...

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is quite simple, just a `WHERE` clause and an `ORDER BY`.

The SQL looks like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.phone = ?
order by t.datetime desc;
```

I am not sure how this translates into your SQL generator, but it does involve removing the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: If I understood the query right, he wants to build a hashmap with phonenumber as key and messages as value. So there is no need for a where condition. I would simply do: `select t.* from t order by t.datetime desc` and then insert messages sequentially at the right place in the hashmap.